# Preventing automatic app redeploy on weblogic server

Tags: weblogic

I have deployed an App in weblogic server (no_stage mode).
When the timestamp of app ear changes, WLS redeploys it on its next restart (hot deploy is the name for this i think).
Is there anyway i can prevent this behavior and make it redeploys only when i specifically tell it to redeploy

Comment: Is your domain running in production or development mode? Please check by logging in to your WebLogic Server web console, going to your domain's configuration/general tab, and checking the "Production Mode" value.

Comment: It is already in production mode. Even then it does auto redeploy on WLS restart